# Add a class to a row when a table has a specified text

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I saved my data from a database in a json and then imported the data into a table.
Now my question is how can i add a class to a row when the name field has a specified value.

I would like to color a complete row of this table if the Name column has a specified value.
Like if the name field contain "hallo" i want that the completly row is in blue.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import data from "../data.json";

const App = () => {
    const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(data);

    return (
        <div className="app-container">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Adress</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {contacts.map((contact)=> (
                        <tr>
                            <td>{contact.id}</td>
                            <td>{contact.name}</td>
                            <td>{contact.adress}</td>
                            <td>{contact.country}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        
    )
                  
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an inline style and adding a ternary condition you can check whether you want that row to be styled or not.
If you want to add more style to that row just add more css in the ***styles*** object

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import data from "./data.json";

const styles = { backgroundColor: "blue" };
const App = () => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(data);
  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Adress</th>
            <th>Country</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {contacts.map((contact) => (
            <tr style={contact.name === "hallo" ? styles : null}>
              <td>{contact.id}</td>
              <td>{contact.name}</td>
              <td>{contact.adress}</td>
              <td>{contact.country}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

If you have a CSS file then just use ternary condition inside className instead of style in .

Answer (score 0):

just add your condition where you wanna specify the className or inline style like this :

```
    {contacts.map((contact)=> (
     <tr className={contact.name.includes("hallo") ? "blue" : "red"}>
      <td>{contact.id}</td>
      <td>{contact.name}</td>
      <td>{contact.adress}</td>
      <td>{contact.country}</td>
   </tr>
 ))}
```

Comment: *try this maybe :* is not an explanation. Please add explanation specifying what is the change and how it fixes the issue.

Comment: @Rajesh
I updated my answer , but try this maybe is because i wasn't sure that this what he wanted !!!
It felt like you were blaming me hey !!!!!!!????

Comment: When you answer, be it right or wrong, you are showing how to do certain thing in a specific way. It will have pros and cons. With just code, you are solving someone's immediate problem but he/she is not learning from it. By adding explanation, you teach them why and how to do something. So next time in a similar but more complex problem, they can find their way